# What is the maximum response header length on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy a service that sets very long headers in some cases.  When running locally, I am able to successfully set and receive long (>8KB) headers without issue.  However, after deploying to cloud run, there is a point where these long headers are getting stripped completely.

It's possible that it's some other issue with my application behaving differently in the two environments, but is there a maximum header length specified by Google Cloud Run or any info at all about the requirements/limitations for setting HTTP headers?

Comment: What HTTP server are you using here? Is it `gunicorn`?

Comment: @DustinIngram I'm using the webserver built into the go standard library.  However, that isn't the issue since when I run it locally, even from within Docker, the headers flow through without issue.  Long headers are only stripped out when I run it inside of cloud run.

Comment: Thanks. Can you include a small example app & Dockerfile I could test with?

Comment: @DustinIngram Here: https://gist.github.com/Ameobea/aa67dfe5c6e2167a8fef9afda3f27b0b

I've run that container locally and can verify that the 10k character header is successfully received by my HTTP client.

I also deployed it to cloud run: https://cloud-run-header-limit-demo-mi7imxlw6a-uc.a.run.app

If you make a request to that service, you'll see that the header is stripped off.

Comment: According to https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants `DefaultMaxHeaderBytes` is 1MB which would be about 10K characters. You may wan to try setting `Server.MaxHeaderBytes` to a higher value and see if your headers come through.

Comment: @DustinIngram again, this isn't an issue with the webserver... If you run the Docker image locally and make a request to it, you'll see that the header is indeed included.  There are 1000000 bytes in a MB and even if go is using some weird character encoding like UTF16 that's still 250k characters to hit the limit.

This isn't an issue with my web server or Docker container - it's a limitation set by the Google Cloud Run infrastructure.  My question was whether there exists documentation or hidden knowledge about what this limit is.

Comment: Good point, looks like the limit is 8190 characters regardless of what HTTP server is being used. I've restored my original answer, and we'll document this accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that any header with a total length greater than 8190 characters (including name, colon and value) will be stripped.

This should be included at https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. I've filed an issue internally to resolve this.

Comment: I'd assume there's probably an undocumented upper-limit that's enforced regardless of the language by Google Cloud’s traffic proxy serving Cloud Run apps.