# Is there a way to increase the request header size limit for Cloud Run or ignore a particular request header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have a Cloud Run application that runs a Python Flask REST Service. The client is sending a request to it with an Authorization Header which is over 10K Characters. The header is not really needed and can be ignored for my use case.

When I was running the application locally, it was working fine with the header, but gives a 400 Error (Error parsing headers: 'limit request headers fields size') when it is deployed in Cloud Run.
On going through a few other questions ([What is the maximum response header length on Google Cloud Run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57473648/what-is-the-maximum-response-header-length-on-google-cloud-run)), I found that there is a limit of 8190 Characters. How can I increase this limit or simply ignore it.